# How to add custom attributes with colons or dots in HAML?

Tags: haml, vue.js

I started working with [Vue.js](http://vuejs.org) where the event handlers require colons and sometimes dots:

`<div v-on:click="doSomething">`

or `<div v-on:keyup.enter="doSomething">`

But those break in HAML:

`%div{ v: { on:click: 'doSomething' } }`

And doubly with the dot: `%div{ v: { on:keyup.enter: 'doSomething' } }`

Is there a way to use them, somehow like the underscore to get a hyphen?

Example: `%div{ data: { my_value: 'something' } }`

will render: `<div data-my-value="something">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use strings instead of symbols for the map keys:

```
%div{ v: { 'on:click' => 'doSomething' } }
```

and

```
%div{ v: { 'on:keyup.enter' => 'doSomething' } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this alternate syntax:

```
%div{"v-on:keyup.enter": 'doSomething'}
```

and

```
%div{"v-on:click": 'doSomething' }
```